# I have enabled IAP and set the firewall rule as per documentation but still I see a warning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, in-app-purchase, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I have enabled IAP and set the firewall rule as per documentation but still I see 'Your firewall configuration needs to make sure that IAP can successfully connect to the individual VM' warning message.

The firewall rule refers to : https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#gcloud

Any idea?

- Created a new VM
- Enabled IAP >> Checked SSH and TCP resources and VM appears there but shows a warning and asks to add firewall rule to complete the network prerequisite.